# Modify a column in table with pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEa1S.png)I'm a pentaho beginner i want to modify a column in my table (my table is an information transfer table, we empty it all the time) after each excel generation, knowing that i have several transformations and the update will be done only in the one transformation how i'm going to do this so that at each execution it will do the update only in the transformation that performs this update (since in the job all transformations will be executed in parallel)

I used the table input component and microsoft excel writer in my transformation, and in the job I used this transformation and the sql scripting component to make my request for the update, but don't forget I have other transformations in this job.

Comment: You'll need to edit your question to make it easier to understand, as is it's a bit chaotic and difficult to discern what you are trying to do. So you have several transformations reading a table and generating an excel that run in parallel. The part on the concurrent writing to a common table where is it performed? In the same transformation writing the excel? Or is there another transformation that needs to run after all the parallel transformations have finished?

Comment: I have several transformations reading a table (this table in my oracle database is a data transfer table, i.e. it is empty most of the time) and generating an excel file which run in parallel in the job. I want to take one of these transformations and I want the status_ column in my table to become sent each time excel is generated.

Comment: Where do you want the STATUS_COLUMN table sent? Are all the transformations reading the same table with different filters or are they different tables with the same structure, or at least the STATUS_COLUMN is the same in all the different tables? In your screenshot you have a SQL 2 step in the job that it's a SQL Script, is this the one you want to execute to "send" that STATUS_COLUMN?

Comment: @AnaGH status_ is a column in the 'MG' table and do all the transformations read the same 'MG' table with different filters and this SQL script I made myself for the modification I don't know if it's right or not in any case T1. 1 contient une table input qui contient une requete select pour passer des valeur en parametre a l'autre transformtion T2.1 et T2.1 contienne a lui meme une table input quitienne une requete select aussi et microsoft excel writer , je veux que a chaque excecution a generation de cette excel la valeur status_ devient sent

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what you are trying to do. So all those T1.N transformations read the same table with different filters and create N excel files (or the T2.N transformations create the excel file, it doesn't matter for this case) You want the "SQL 2" to read the "STATUS" column in the table and update the value or the value in some other table after all the T1.N and T2.N transformations are finished or only after the T2.1 transformation has finished?

Comment: yes that's it but it reads the "STATUS" column in the same table and updates the value to  sent after the excel generation, knowing that the modification I want to make it just in the T2.1 transformation.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if I'm understanding your problem correctly, you have N transformations T1.N followed by T2.N, that are executed in parallel, reading from one table but applying different filters to generate different excel files.

After ALL the parallel transformations are finished, you want to read/update the STATUS column in the source table (probably marking it as "row" processed or just take it to another table or whatever) and you want to do it once, that is why in your original screenshot you have the "SQL 2" script following the T2.1 transformation, but in reality you want it to be executed after all the T2.N transformations have finished, so the structure of the job in your original screenshot isn't valid. You can't put it where all the parallel branches converge, because it would be executed N times.

So instead of using one job, you use two jobs. In job J1 you put all the parallel executions:
[image: Structure of J1]

You don't need a "Success step" to mark a job as completed, the job will be marked as finished when all the steps have finished correctly, I like to use it for clarity when running jobs sequentially, but for parallel jobs I prefer to omit it because it can be interpreted like the job will finished when **any** of the branches has finished.

Also, in your screenshot you haven't marked the entries to run in parallel (the "=" symbol and --- lines following the Start entry). To do that you right click in the Start entry and select the option to "*Run next entries in parallel*"

Then you create a second job, J2, that launches sequentially your first job and afterwards your SQL 2 script:
[image: J2 run sequentially]

Now the SQL 2 script will be launched only after J1 has finished sucessfully.

Comment: Thank you, but according to your answer what I understood is that all the modifications will be made by all the transformations whereas my need is to make the modification only after the generation of excel of T2.1 i.e. with each generation of an excel only the status corresponds to this excel will be modified.

Comment: So what is the problem with your Job? What is it that you are asking?

Comment: help me solve this problem update tabe_name
set STATUS_='Generated'
where pk_=${pk_} I get this error: 2024/01/22 08:59:15 - SQL - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : An error occurred executing this job entry : 
2024/01/22 08:59:15 - SQL - Couldn't execute SQL: update tabe_name
set STATUS_='Generated'
where pk_=${pk_}
2024/01/22 08:59:15 - SQL - 
2024/01/22 08:59:15 - SQL - Non supported SQL92 token at position: 72